# Handling expired Azure AD session in asp.net core and angular app

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an Asp.Net core project hosting an angular application within it. There are a couple of API controllers in the asp.net core project. These controllers are called from within the Angular App.

The asp.net core app is protected by Azure AD authentication using OpenIdConnect along with Cookies. What I am looking at is how should I handle the token expiry for an overnight idle session for the user.

Currently, if a user will resume his browser session which is expired, he is thrown an exception on the async API call made from the Angular App. How should I make Angular App re-direct user back to the login page for the Azure AD application?.

Comment: Are you using ADAL? Are you getting back a refresh token?

Comment: Yes I am using ADAL. And I do get the refresh token.

Comment: Is the refresh token expired by the time the user comes back? I would simply get a new token using the refresh token you have for the user. There is an ADAL function precisely for this: [AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshToken Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenbyrefreshtoken.aspx). If the refresh token is also expired, you might as well start over the authentication process.

Comment: Can't we just call "AcquireTokenAsync" and wouldn't that use the refresh token to generate a new access token?. Also, if the session was re-set, wouldn't that mean, we have to re-start the whole process of authentication again as the tokens were re-set?. And how can I re-start the authentication process?. By asking user to close the browser and re-start?.

Comment: I moved the token caching management to Sql Server and with complete app resets , the application is now able to resume without losing user session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the token expiry issue by moving the token cache to Sql Server. With this done, if current in-memory token is expired, the refresh token from sql server is used to generate a new access token.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a hidden iframe in your web app that makes a request against your server every 45 minutes or so. That way, your token will always be valid while your application is running.

[This blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/) talks about this issue and explain your options, including showing a script that makes the request on a scheduled interval.